# Dot product between a matrix and a 1d-array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to perform the dot product of two matrices in numpy. However, one of them actually has the same value in each row. Something like:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

For optimization purposes, I only store one column as a 1d array.

**Is there a way** to calculate the dot product between this and a usual 2d matrix **without** having to explicitly create the above matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have an array:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2])
```

which represents a matrix like:

```
>>> np.repeat(a[:,np.newaxis], 5, 1)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

and you want a dot product with matrix m:

```
m = np.arange(5*4).reshape(5,4)
```

you may use:

```
a[:,np.newaxis] * np.sum(m, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I also found that `a.reshape(len(a), 1)` is faster than using `np.newaxis` (at least with 300 dimensions)

Answer (score 4):

When you do the dot product of two arrays, you are computing the dot product of every row of the first array with every column of the second. If your matrix-that-fits-in-a-vector (MTFIAV) is the first operand of the dot product, it is easy to see that you can factor the repeating value from the dot product, and do a single multiplication with the result of summing up every column of the second array:

```
>>> a = np.arange(3)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> aa = np.repeat(a, 5).reshape(len(a), -1)
>>> aa
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])

>>> np.dot(aa, b)
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0],
       [ 40,  45,  50,  55],
       [ 80,  90, 100, 110]])
>>> np.outer(a, b.sum(axis=0))
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0],
       [ 40,  45,  50,  55],
       [ 80,  90, 100, 110]])
```

If your MTFIAV is the second operand, it isn't hard to see that the result will also be a MTFIAV, and that its vector representation can be obtained computing the dot product of the first operand with the vector:

```
>>> c = np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3)

>>> np.dot(c, aa)
array([[ 5,  5,  5,  5,  5],
       [14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
       [23, 23, 23, 23, 23],
       [32, 32, 32, 32, 32]])
>>> np.dot(c, a)
array([ 5, 14, 23, 32])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to avoid creating the full matrix because it is slower.

Comment: The code using the full matrix is only there to show that results are correct. For both orderings, the second call produces the same result as the call with the full matrix, without having to create it.